# Adding a variable "attribute" to a variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, dice

I am writing some JavaScript code for my webapp. I need to make a variable that has an attribute linked to it. ie: `Dice1.PowerUp`

So when I code I can roll a dice that is different when the powerup linked to it is at 0, 1 or 2. Do I have to code 2 different variable and set them at the same time or can I just code a linked variable that will work like an attribute to sort it.

While waiting for an answer I am coding it with 2 variables that will be set at the same time.

Code:

```
var consDie = new Array(3); 
//Implanté les élément de constance des dés. 
for (var i = 0; i <= 2; i++){ 
    consDie[i] = 12 - (i * 2); 
    console.log("D" + consDie[i]); 
    //Ça marché... holy macaroony! 
} 
var consNDice = 6; //Constante pour le nombre de dés 
var consAlign = {
    UnAl : consDie[2], 
    Bal : consDie[1], 
    Phys : consDie[0], 
    Ment : consDie[0]
}; 
//declaration of an object that contain the kind of dice that is rolled by powerup
```

Comment: Here is my code: 
'var consDie = new Array(3); //Implanté les élément de constance des dés. 
   for (var i = 0; i <= 2; i++){
    consDie[i] = 12 - (i * 2);
    console.log("D" + consDie[i]); //Ça marché... holy macaroony!     
   }
  
   var consNDice = 6; //Constante pour le nombre de dés
   var consAlign = {UnAl : consDie[2], Bal : consDie[1], Phys : consDie[0], Ment : consDie[0]}; 
   //declaration of an object that contain the kind of dice that is rolled by powerup'

Comment: You can add code by indenting it four spaces (or you can use the Code Sample button at the top of the editor), and it must have an empty line before the code block. Try editing your question to look at the way I put your code in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create a class for the dice:

```
function Dice (power_up) {
    this.power_up = power_up;

    this.rollDice = function() {
        return Math.floor(Math.random()*6) * power_up;
    };
}
```

so you can create a dice object with a power up associated, and then use the rollDice function to get the value

Comment: Sorry to answer my own question but I want to post my code and don't know how to do it. 

    var consDie = new Array(3); //Implanté les élément de constance des dés. 
    for (var i = 0; i <= 2; i++){
 consDie[i] = 12 - (i * 2);
 console.log("D" + consDie[i]);      
 }  
    var consNDice = 6; //Constante pour le nombre de dés
    //declaration of an object that contain the kind of dice that is rolled by powerup 
    var consAlign = {UnAl : consDie[2], Bal : consDie[1], Phys : consDie[0], Ment : consDie[0]};

Comment: So now I can creat a function and throw the object into it. Then roll the appropriate dice for each? 

so I can have a function like this. 

    function Dice (power_up) {
    this.power_up = power_up;

    this.rollDice = function() {
        return Math.floor(Math.random()*consAlign);
    };
    }

Does it looks good?

Comment: sorry cannot try it right now,i'm on cellphone but seems fine. i'll check again tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

You might try using an object literal:
http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/obj_lit.php

Or you could make a full class:
http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/